# Using filters from other classes within rules method in Yii 2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Consider this code inside a model:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['company_name', 'first_name', 'last_name'], 'sanitize'],
        //........
    ];
}
```

`sanitize` is a custom method inside the current class, which is:

```
public function sanitize($attribute) {
    $this->{$attribute} = general::stripTagsConvert($this->{$attribute}, null, true);
}
```

Now this method obviously will come in handy in many models so I don't want to keep repeating the same code in every model. Is there a way I can reference another class in the rules in place of the current `sanitize` method name which is binded to the current class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible.

Create separate validator. Let assume it's called `SanitizeValidator` and placed in `common/components` folder.

Your custom validator must extend from framework base validator and override `validateAttribute()` method. Put your logic inside this method:

```
use yii\validators\Validator;

class SanitizeValidator extends Validator
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAttribute($model, $attribute)
    {
        $model->$attribute = general::stripTagsConvert($model->$attribute, null, true);
    }
}
```

Then in model you can attach this validator like this:

```
use common/components/SanitizeValidator;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['company_name', 'first_name', 'last_name'], SanitizeValidator::className()],
    ];
}
```

Check the official documentation about custom validators [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#rules%28%29-detail) and [there](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html).

Comment: But it's not a validator, it's a filter, so I would need to return the data so it can ba assigned to the correct property. Is that going to work correctly?

Comment: Yes. You can see for example how built-in DefaultValueValidator is implemented. It also more filter than validator (I think it's called like so just for the consistence). In that case it just sets the default value if it was not filled by user.

Comment: So do I just do `return $this->$attribute = general::stripTagsConvert($this->$attribute, null, true);` and it will update the correct property name in the model?

Comment: Yes, but you should not return anytning, instead add errors via addError() method (if they are exist). In your case just assign sanitized value.

Comment: So return is not needed there.

Comment: Also, don't you need to use `$model` and not `$this`?

Comment: Sorry, the $model is needed instead of $this. Fixed answer.

Comment: You missed one in `stripTagsConvert` ;) Also, last question..... how does the validator know what method in the class to use when you only are referencing the class name in the rules declaration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67978/discussion-between-arogachev-and-brett).